# Installing zPanel on CentOS 5.3

Tags: linux, centos, installation

I am trying to install zPanel following [these instructions](http://www.unixmen.com/zpanel-the-best-alternative-for-cpanel/), but the install script fails with the following error:

```
 ./installer-x86_64-install.sh.x: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: 
 bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Some research online lead me verify that I have support for 32 bit packages. I ran the install commands below, but the system indicated that these packages are already installed.

```
yum install glibc.i686
yum install ld-linux.so.2
```

Any ideas how I can install zPanel on my VPS?

Comment: It's 2013, not 2009, how did you end up with a VPS with "CentOS 5.3" on it?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 4):

Those instructions are for installing zPanel on CentOS **6.3**. Try [these](http://planet.zpanelcp.com/doku.php?id=zpanel_6:articles:installation:zpanel_6.1.x_centos) CentOS 5.5 instructions instead.